# Jquery .offset() setter doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a functional for some site, which helps to group objects in one div and then change it as group, resize, rotate, etc. I have an issue with saving parametres of edited objects inside div. After resizing i have to correct their position on the workarea, but it seems that jquery .offset() doesn't work.

```
function grouped_objects_saving(merged_block_id){ 
    var count = $("#"+merged_block_id+" > .merged").length;
    var angle = transform_to_angle(merged_block_id);
    var scaleX = transform_to_scale(merged_block_id, "x");
    var scaleY = transform_to_scale(merged_block_id, "y");
    var brows = browser();
    var topOff = [];
    var leftOff = [];
    var objId = [];
    var width = [];
    var height = [];
    var imageAngle = [];
    var resultAngle = [];
    var transform = "";
    var check = false;
        switch(brows){
            case "Chrome":
                transform = $('#'+merged_block_id).css('-webkit-transform');
            break;
            case "IE":
                transform = $('#'+merged_block_id).css('-ms-transform');
            break;
            case "Firefox":
                transform = $('#'+merged_block_id).css('-moz-transform');
            break;
            default:
                transform = $('#'+merged_block_id).css('transform');
            break;
        }
        for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
            objId[i] = $("#"+merged_block_id+" > .merged").eq(i).attr('id');
            topOff[i] = $("#"+merged_block_id+" > .merged").eq(i).offset().top;
            leftOff[i] = $("#"+merged_block_id+" > .merged").eq(i).offset().left;
            width[i] = $("#"+objId[i]).width();
            height[i] = $("#"+objId[i]).height();
            imageAngle[i] = transform_to_angle(objId[i]);
            resultAngle[i] = imageAngle[i]+angle;
            $("#"+objId[i]).offset({top: topOff[i], left: leftOff[i]});
        }
        for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
            $("#"+objId[i]).appendTo($('#workarea'));
            switch(brows){
                case "Chrome":
                    $("#"+objId[i]).css({'-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+resultAngle[i]+'deg)'});
                break;
                case "IE":
                    $("#"+objId[i]).css({'-ms-transform': 'rotate('+resultAngle[i]+'deg)'});
                break;
                case "Firefox":
                    $("#"+objId[i]).css({'-moz-transform': 'rotate('+resultAngle[i]+'deg)'});
                break;
                default:
                    $("#"+objId[i]).css({'transform': 'rotate('+resultAngle[i]+'deg)'});
                break;
            }
            $("#"+objId[i]).width(width[i]*scaleX);
            $("#"+objId[i]).height(height[i]*scaleY);
            $("#"+objId[i]).appendTo($('#'+merged_block_id));
            //$("#"+objId[i]).addClass("editable selectable"); 
            if (i==count-1) {
                check = true;
            }
        }
        if (check==true){
            for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
                console.log('$("#'+objId[i]+'").offset({top:'+topOff[i]+', left:'+leftOff[i]+'});');
                $("#"+objId[i]).offset({top: topOff[i], left: leftOff[i]});
            }
        }
    return true;
}
```

Problem is in the last string:

```
$("#"+objId[i]).offset({top: topOff[i], left: leftOff[i]});
```

If i copy the string which comes from console:

```
console.log('$("#'+objId[i]+'").offset({top:'+topOff[i]+', left:'+leftOff[i]+'});'
```

for example

```
$("#custom-image-58clx").offset({top:393.089111328125, left:407.17822265625});
```

and use it in console, that works, offset sets correctly.

I have no idea why it doesn't work from code.

Comment: Maybe the selector doesn't find anything at the time it runs? Try `console.log($("#"+objId[i]).length)` (will log 0 if nothing is found)

Comment: It always returns 1.

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: I've found out that if i delete the string $("#"+objId[i]).appendTo($('#'+merged_block_id));offset will work, so it seems that the problem is with position inside parent div. But anyway i don't understand why .offset() works correctly with console doesn't work from code...

Comment: @Pete There's no any errors in console.

Comment: Just wondering, why do two loops - it seems that your `check` will always be set to true so why not just set the offset in the first loop and why do you append the object to `workarea` only to move it to `merged_block_id`?  You should also think about caching `$("#"+objId[i])` or chaining your events for better performance

Answer (score 0):

I still got no idea why original code didn't work and .offset was not applied, but after changing code to the one below, it worked fine.

```
function grouped_objects_saving(merged_block_id, type){ 
    var count = $("#"+merged_block_id+" > .merged").length;
    var angle = transform_to_angle(merged_block_id);
    var scaleX = transform_to_scale(merged_block_id, "x");
    var scaleY = transform_to_scale(merged_block_id, "y");
    console.log("scaleX: " + scaleX);
    console.log("scaleY: " + scaleY);
    var brows = browser();
    var transform = "";
        switch(brows){
            case "Chrome":
                transform = $('#'+merged_block_id).css('-webkit-transform');
            break;
            case "IE":
                transform = $('#'+merged_block_id).css('-ms-transform');
            break;
            case "Firefox":
                transform = $('#'+merged_block_id).css('-moz-transform');
            break;
            default:
                transform = $('#'+merged_block_id).css('transform');
            break;
        }
    var topOff = [];
    var leftOff = [];
    var objId = [];
    var width = [];
    var height = [];
    var imageAngle = [];
    var resultAngle = [];
    for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
        objId[i] = $("#"+merged_block_id+" > .merged").eq(i).attr('id');
        topOff[i] = $("#"+merged_block_id+" > .merged").eq(i).offset().top;
        leftOff[i] = $("#"+merged_block_id+" > .merged").eq(i).offset().left;
        width[i] = $("#"+objId[i]).width();
        height[i] = $("#"+objId[i]).height();
        imageAngle[i] = transform_to_angle(objId[i]);
        resultAngle[i] = imageAngle[i]+angle;
        $("#"+objId[i]).offset({top: topOff[i], left: leftOff[i]});
        console.log("resultAngle: "+ resultAngle[i]);
        console.log("ObjId: "+objId[i]);
        console.log("topOff: "+topOff[i]);
        console.log("leftOff: "+leftOff[i]); 
    }
   for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
               $("#"+objId[i]).removeAttr('style');
               $("#"+objId[i]).appendTo($('#workarea'));
               $("#"+objId[i]).css({
                   'width': width[i]*scaleX+"px",
                   'height': height[i]*scaleY+"px",
                   '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+resultAngle[i]+'deg)',
                   '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+resultAngle[i]+'deg)',
                   '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+resultAngle[i]+'deg)',
                   'transform': 'rotate('+resultAngle[i]+'deg)',
                   'position': 'absolute'
               }).offset({top: topOff[i], left: leftOff[i]});
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I suppose that it was caused by wrong sequence of actions.